# fingerprints for Schengen visa vs national visa

Tags: visa, student-visa, schengen

I applied for student visa for Czech republic visa (D) but was refused and they took my fingerprints during the process , now I want to apply for polish student visa so I'm confused about previous fingerprints if it was considered as Schengen visa fingerprints or irrelevant.
Should I say YES about part of Fingerprints collected previously for the purpose of applying for a Schengen visa for national visa D of Poland ????
I hope to get the right answer from you guyz
Thanks
 [image][image]

Comment: Can you ask the Polish authorities or the visa processing center?

Comment: I didn't ask them yet I read that VIS is used only for short term visa